# PriorityQueue varargs error when extending Ordering to accomodate class objects

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, priority-queue

My goal is to create a function that takes varargs of 2 or more objects when initializing a PriorityQueue containing said objects.

The relevant code is:

```
case class Topic(topic: String, usageFrequency: Long = 1)  

object FreqOrdering extends Ordering[Topic] {
  def compare(a: Topic, b:Topic) = -(a.usageFrequency compare b.usageFrequency)}  

def initPriQu(a : Topic, b: Topic, c: Topic*): PriorityQueue[Topic] = {
return PriorityQueue(a,b,c)(FreqOrdering)}
```

Error in sbt (Scala 2):

> [error]  found   : TopicTrenderInit.FreqOrdering.type
>   [error]  required: scala.math.Ordering[Equals]
>   [error] Note: TopicTrenderInit.Topic <: Equals (and TopicTrenderInit.FreqOrdering.type <: scala.math.Ordering[TopicTrenderInit.Topic]), but trait Ordering is invariant in type T.
>   [error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Equals`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>   [error]     return PriorityQueue(a,b,c)(FreqOrdering)
>   [error]                                 ^
>   [error] /home/aaron-laptop/Documents/Scala/topic_trender100/src/main/scala/main.scala:48:25: type mismatch;
>   [error]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Equals]
>   [error]  required: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[TopicTrenderInit.Topic]
>   [error] Note: Equals >: TopicTrenderInit.Topic, but class PriorityQueue is invariant in type A.
>   [error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: TopicTrenderInit.Topic`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>   [error]     return PriorityQueue(a,b,c)(FreqOrdering)

When there is no '*' indicating a vararg everything works, no errors. I think what confuses me the worst is the required: scala.math.Ordering[Equals] error I'm seeing. I also read an article on pattern matching, but I feel i'll have to read more on it to understand implementation. What's going on here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the way you are building the `PriorityQueue`. You are passing it two values of type `Topic` and one of type `Seq[Topic]` so the result is `PriorityQueue[Any]`.

This should work:

```
def initPriQu(a : Topic, b: Topic, c: Topic*): mutable.PriorityQueue[Topic] =
  mutable.PriorityQueue(Seq(a, b) ++ c:_*)(FreqOrdering)
```

Also, don't use `return`.

Comment: in terms of performance _(and knowing that Seq will probably be a List in runtime)_  will it be better to concatenate both Seqs or to use flatten?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I think for `List` the fastest implemetnation will be `a +: b +: c:_*` because it will use `+:` from `List` which will be just a wrapper over `::` which is `O(1)`. However for other underlying collections performance might be pretty bad because 2 copies might be required. The suggested here `++` for `List` is a wrapper over `:::` which will be pretty good as well without any big sacrifices for other possible types. AFAIK your `flatten` is not overridden in any class so there are no optimizations at all and actually it is harder to add optimization to `flatten`.

Comment: @SergGr after searching a bit I found that _varargs_ are implemented using a `WrappedArray` not a `List`, so yes Tim's solution using `++` will be the best one. I will update my answer to use it too.

Comment: thank you, all these comments are enlightening. What is the reason to not use the return keyword? Is it for better readability or a more functional reason?

Comment: @A.Lopez The problem with `return` is that it is not necessary in the simple cases and can have unexpected behaviour in complex cases. In the simple case you can just use an expression as the return value. In complex cases it can jump out of multiple nested blocks and it is not always clear where it jumps to!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when you pass `a, b, c` to the **Factory** of `PriorityQueue`. What the compilers see is that you passed three arguments of type `A` and the only super type between those tree is `Equals`.
That is because `a` & `b` are `Topics`, which as a case class extends `Equals`, and `c` is of type `Seq[Topic]` *(a varargs arguments is passed as a `Seq`)*, which also extends `Equals`.
And that is why it is asking for a `Ordering[Equals]`.

You may fix it as follows.
*(Note this is quite ugly and maybe innificient, you may consider just recieve one varargs instead of `a` & `b` and then `c`)*

```
// It will be good to have this as an implicit so you don't have to pass it explicitly
// every time you need to.
// And it is always preferable to have an implicit val with an explicit type signature
// than an implicit object.
implicit val TopicOrdering: Ordering[Topic] = new math.Ordering[Topic] {
  override def compare(a: Topic, b:Topic): Int =
    -(a.usageFrequency compare b.usageFrequency)
}

import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue
def initPriQu(a: Topic, b: Topic, others: Topic*): PriorityQueue[Topic] =
  // 1. Don't use return in scala.
  // 2. Here I made a Seq of Seqs of Topic - Seq[Seq[Topic]]
  //    then I flatten it to have a Seq of Topic - Seq[Topic]
  //    and finally used the ':_*' operator to turn a Seq into a varargs.
  PriorityQueue((Seq(a, b) ++ others): _*)
```